# Lunar Release' does not have a Release file

Tags: ros

I'm trying to setup ROS2 on Ubuntu but I'm getting the following errors. Any suggestions on this? Thanks

````
Err:6 http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu lunar Release
 404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]

E: The repository 'http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu lunar Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details. ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to edit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2.list (or whichever file has the apt setup for ros2). Replace "lunar" with your ubuntu codename (for instance, "bionic", "focal",  "jammy", etc).